# How to refactor this call to refresh state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, code-cleanup

I want to know how improve this calls in order to not repeat always the same sentence to refresh the state...
I don't need any huge refactor, only inputs like: you need to put this call inside a function and call it when you want... something like this...

```
export const CategoriesPage = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState<Category[]>([]);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const handleCreateCategory = (newCategory: CategoryCreate, file: File) => {
    createCategoryHelper(newCategory, file)
      .then(() => {
        getCategoriesHelper().then(setCategories);
      })
      .finally(() => handleClose());
  };

  const handleDeleteCategory = (categoryId: Id) => {
    SwalHelper.delete().then(() => {
      deleteCategoryHelper(categoryId).then(() =>
        getCategoriesHelper().then(setCategories)
      );
    });
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  const handleModal = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCategoriesHelper().then(setCategories);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <PageTitle title="Categories" />
      <FilterBar>
        <Button type="button" background="green" onClick={handleModal}>
          + Add new
        </Button>
      </FilterBar>
      {showModal && (
        <ModalPortal onClose={handleClose}>
          <CreateCategoryForm
            createCategory={(category, file: File) => {
              handleCreateCategory(category, file);
            }}
          />
        </ModalPortal>
      )}

      <ListGrid columns={3}>
        {categories.map((category) => {
          const { id: categoryId } = category;
          return (
            <CategoryCard
              key={categoryId}
              {...category}
              onClick={() => handleDeleteCategory(categoryId)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ListGrid>
    </>
  );
};
```

1. When component is ***mounting***, on useEffect, fills the state with response in order to create a list.
2. When a category is ***created***, I call to setState again to refresh the list.
3. Same on ***delete***, on then, refresh again to update the list.

Three times calling the same sentence

```
getCategoriesHelper().then(setCategories)
```

This is getCategoriesHelper:

```
export const getCategoriesHelper = async () => {
  const service = new CategoryServiceImplementation(apiConfig);
  const uploadImageService = new AmplifyS3Service();
  const repository = new CategoryRepositoryImplementation(
    service,
    uploadImageService
  );
  const useCase = new GetCategoriesUseCaseImplementation(repository);
  return await useCase.getCategories();
};
```

Is there any way to make this code much cleaner and reusable?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is write, and all calls are made as they are designed to do